# Problema em expressão regular no .htaccess

Tags: regex, htaccess

Tenho as seguintes regras no meu arquivo `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^first-login/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./first-login.php?userKey=$1&step=1
RewriteRule ^first-login/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?([0-9]+)$ ./first-login.php?userKey=$1&step=2
```

A primeira funciona, eu utilizo a URL `http://localhost/first-login/Xmi5drXyH9ngm4` e ele preenche as variáveis `$_GET["userKey"] e $_GET["step"]` com os valores corretos.

Essa página é um wizard com alguns passos para a primeira configuração de conta do usuário, ao final de cada passo, eu redireciono o usuário para a mesma página apenas mudando o valor do `step`, então apresento o conteúdo direcionado. URL utilizada: `http://localhost/first-login/Xmi5drXyH9ngm4?2`.

**O problema:** mesmo com o `?2` no final, eu estou sendo redirecionado de acordo com a primeira regra, por isso minha variável `$_GET["step"]` sempre está recebendo o valor 1. O que há de errado nessas expressões regulares? Por enquanto eu estou fazendo o processo de esconder/mostrar o conteúdo com jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu conheço o mode `RewriteRule` ele converte os `GETs` de `?=` para `/`

Em meus testes, a razão de não estar funcionando é que a expressão :

```
RewriteRule ^first-login/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?([0-9]+)$ ./first-login.php?userKey=$1&step=2
```

nunca é capturada por causa do `?` que na url é `/` alem de que se você quer capturar o `?` literal você deve utilizar `\?`

tente alterar a regra para :

```
RewriteRule    ^first-login/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ ./first-login.php?userKey=$1&step=2
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [RegExr](http://regexr.com):

> *`?` Matches 0 or 1 of the preceding token, effectively making it optional.*
>
> `?` Corresponde a 0 ou 1 ocorrências do elemento precedente, fazendo-o opcional.

por outro lado:

> *`\?` Matches a "?" character (char code 63).*
>
> `\?` Corresponde a um caractere "?" (código 63).

Para que o seu código funcione como desejado, escape o '?' na segunda regra o precedendo com '\'.

Além disso, na segunda regra use `$2` para representar o digito do passo na URL.

O novo código ficaria assim:

```
RewriteRule ^first-login\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./first-login.php?userKey=$1&step=1
RewriteRule ^first-login\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\?([0-9]+)$ ./first-login.php?userKey=$1&step=$2
```